# Why ifelse is not the same as if statement?

Tags: r

Given data:

```
condition <- rep(TRUE, 10)
varExist <- c(FALSE, rep(TRUE, 9))
cond <- list(c(rep(TRUE, 6) ,rep(FALSE, 4)))
```

When there is a condition:

```
condition <- if(varExist[1]){
  condition
}else{
  condition & !cond[[1]]
}
```

Then I wanted to convert the `if` statement into `ifelse` statement:

```
condition <- ifelse(varExist[1], condition, condition & !cond[[1]])
```

But the results differ:
Expected:

```
> condition
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

but there is:

```
> condition
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: `ifelse()` is vectorized while `if()` is not. See `help("ifelse")` and `help("if")`

Comment: google "what is a vectorized function in r"